# Deserialzation (XML) of multiple occurrences of the same tag under the root using JMS Serialization

Tags: xml, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to de-serialize the following using the jmsserializerbundle in symfony2:

```
   <root>
      <Tag></Tag>
      <Tag></Tag>
      <Tag></Tag>
      ...
   </root>
```

Since the root node is essentially the parent container for the multiple occurrences of Tag,de-serialization appears impossible.

```
   /**
    * @XMLRoot("root")
    */
   class root {

       /**
        * @Type("ArrayCollection<string>")
        */
       private $Tag;
   }
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

This behaviour was added/fixed in the 0.13 branch